# Understanding this MathOverflow answer involving modular arithmetic on a power series

Tags: combinatorics, modular-arithmetic, power-series

A recent [MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/409002/collecting-alternative-proofs-for-the-oddity-of-catalan) was a top network question asking for a proof that the only odd Catalan numbers $C_n$ have $n=2^r - 1$ for nonnegative integer $r$. There were many good answers, but I find it difficult to fully understand one of the [top answers](https://mathoverflow.net/q/409015), which I will partially reproduce here.

---

Defining $F= \sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n x^{n+1}$ and using the well known fact that $G= \sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n x^{n}$ satsifies $G = xG^2 + 1$, one has that $F=x+F^2$.

The proof considers $F \pmod 2$ and iteratively plugs in $F=x+F^2$ and simplifies the resulting expression using $(a+b)^{2^r} \equiv a^{2^r} + b^{2^r} \pmod 2$. The $\pmod 2$ will be omitted in the below.

$$\begin{array}{rl}
F \; = \!\! & x + F^2 \cr
 = \!\! & x + (x+F^2)^2 \equiv x + x^2 + F^4 \cr
 = \!\! & x + x^2 + (x+F^2)^4 \equiv x + x^2 + x^4 + F^8 \cr
 = \!\! & x + x^2 + x^4 + (x+F^2)^8 \equiv x + x^2 + x^4 + x^8 + F^{16} \cr
 = \!\! & \cdots \cr
 \equiv \!\! & x + x^2 + x^4 + x^8 + x^{16} + x^{32} + x^{64} + \cdots \cr
\end{array}$$

That is, $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n x^{n+1} \equiv  x + x^2 + x^4 + x^8 + x^{16} + x^{32} + x^{64} + \cdots  \pmod 2  $$

---

While each step makes some sense, I am missing some big pieces.

$a)$ Though it is clear for **integers** $a$ and $b$ that $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab+b^2 \equiv a^2 +b^2 \pmod 2$, I don't see why $(x+F^2)^2 = x^2 + 2 x F^2 + F^4 \equiv x^2 + F^4 \pmod 2$. My consuion is that there is no guarantee that $x$ and $F^2$ are integers and hence no guarantee that $2 x F^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 2$.

$b)$ Furthermore, it is not clear to me that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n x^{n+1} \equiv x + x^2 +x^4+x^8 +x^{16} +... \pmod 2$ would imply that each of $C_0 \equiv 1 \pmod 2$, $C_1 \equiv 1 \pmod 2$, $C_2 \equiv 0 \pmod 2$, $C_3 \equiv 1 \pmod 2$, etc. Though it is true one can set equal the coefficients of two power series that are equal to one another through the uniqueness of series expansions, it seems to me that the answer to $a)$ could potentially foil such an argument depending on the nature of $x$ and whether it is restricted to be an integer or not.

---

I suspect my confusions and suspicions are "not even wrong" and are born out of my ignorance of how to manipulate power series with modular arithmetic. What does it mean to apply modular arithmetic to a power series? How can I understand the key steps applying modular arithmetic in the proof above; in particular, how does one resolve the points I raised in $a)$ and $b)$?

Comment: Consider these power series as *formal* power series with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_2$ (just like polynomials). Two such series are the same iff they have the same coefficients.